# Using AVERAGEIF to calculate time sheet effectiveness over time, unexpected result

Tags: excel, average

I am trying to use AVERAGEIF to get a sort of "running total" average for a team's timesheet, but I am getting a nondescript error.

Here is a view of the worksheet:
[Worksheet 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTxPE.png)

COLUMNS B through AC cover the project lifecycle.

ROWS 4 through 13 represent how their timesheet actuals performed against their estimated time.

ROWS 14 through 19 are not really relevant to this problem.  I probably shouldn't have included them in the screenshot.

In COLUMN AD I am attempting to get an AVERAGE for just the weeks in the past.  However...  despite using the AVERAGEIF formula as it seems to be prescribed, it's not working.

The formula in AD4 is *=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF($B$2:$AC$2,"< TODAY()",$B4:$AC4),"-")*
[Worksheet 002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMz6p.png)

Am I just doing something wrong here?  Is there a better way to do this that does not involve Macros?

Comment: try `"<" & TODAY()`

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you!